# Handler.dispatchMessage is taking most of the application time in traceview

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse to develop an android application. the application is dictionary and the database is located in SQL azure (online) and i am using RESTful to connect with it. I am using traceview to make it perform better. I found out that Handler.dispatchMessage is taking 86% of the time.
when i clicked Handler.dispatchMessage in the profile panel it shows where the Handler.dispatchMessage happens, it happen more than 100 time.  can you tell me if that oky or it is too many and if it is too many how can i solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Use Traceview to figure out exactly where your time is being spent.

Answer (score 4):

Handler.dispatchMessage() pretty much controls everything that happens in Android. An Android thread has an associated Handler, MessageQueue, and Looper. For something to happen, the system puts a Message on the Queue, which gets passed to the Handler running on the thread. In response, the code on the thread does something. Any time any Android component does something, it happens in response to dispatchMessage().

I'd look at higher levels. How long are your HTTP connections taking? How long does it take to get a response from a database request. Database operations take time, and network operations take even *more* time. If this amount of time makes your app look "slow", you should do more work off the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answar about what Handler.dispatchMessage() means and do that helped me alot. Actully i am doing my HTTP connections with AsyncTask.

Comment: I found out that progress dialog takes 5.8% and alert dialog takes 5% of the time. I surrounded my code in every function with try/catch and in the catch i display an alert dialog with the error massege. Is there a better way than dialog.